# Any type of positioners doesn't work with user-defined element

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2

There's a code of Sensor element. It is like a base class for other sensor types elements:

```
Rectangle {
    property real value: 0

    property alias imageWidth: image.width
    property alias imageSource: image.source
    property alias displayWidth: display.width

    width: Math.max(image.width, display.width)
    height: image.height + display.height

    border.width: 1

    Rectangle {
        id: display
        width: 40
        height: 20
        border.width: 1
        color: "lightgreen"

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: value
            font.pixelSize: parent.width * 0.3;
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: image
        width: display.width * 0.5
        anchors.top: display.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: display.horizontalCenter
        source: "qrc:/images/temperature.png"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
}
```

If I put sensors in a `Column`, they are located properly.

The implementation of derived type - `Pressure`:

```
Item {
    Sensor {
        imageSource: "qrc:/images/pressure.png"
        imageWidth: displayWidth * 0.4
    }
}
```

But if I put `Pressure` sensors in a `Row` or a `Column`, all sensors just overlap each other.

```
Column {
        spacing: 10
        Pressure {}
        Pressure {}
        Pressure {}
}
```

[Pressures and Sensors comparison (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q0Yi.jpg)

Could you please explain what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it seems I've found the answer by myself.

`Items` in derived class like `Pressure` don't have own width and height. If I delete `Item`, it works properly:

```
Sensor {
    imageSource: "qrc:/images/pressure.png"
    imageWidth: displayWidth * 0.4
}
```

Comment: Hi, just as a small idea: You *might* want to read about [`implicitWidth/Height`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitHeight-prop) - It is not necessary what you want here semantic-wise, but often it is good practice to set the implicit values in the root node, rather than `width/height` directly.